# Vue .filter is not a function on reactive data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am building a Shopping Cart. On my order form I am trying to create a shipping estimate based on the shipping method selected. Shipping methods are retrieved from an api end point so I have made the data reactive.

```
const shipping_estimate = computed(() => {
    // produces an error
    return localState.shippingMethods.filter(function (el) {
         return el.price === shippingMethods[selectedShippingMethod];
    });
});

const localState = reactive({
    removingCartItem: false,
    paymentProcessing: false,
    stripe: {},
    cardElement: {},
    customer: {},
    orderError: null,
    loading: false,
    selectedShippingMethod: null,
    shippingMethods: {}
}); 

onMounted(async () => {
    localState.loading = true;

    await axios
       .get("/api/shipping-method")
        .then((response) => {
            localState.shippingMethods = response.data.data
            localState.loading = false;
    })
});
```

The error I get is:

```
TypeError: localState.shippingMethods.filter is not a function
```

But if I check in Vue dev tools, `localState.shippingMethods` is an array.

How can I filter data that is an element in a reactive object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `shippingMethods` property should be initialized as an empty an array:

```js
const localState = reactive({
   ...
    shippingMethods:[]
});
```

because the computed property at the first rendering evaluates that property however it's empty.